# git or svn responsitory with two different "views" of the code, one with certain directories hidden

Tags: git, svn

I'd like to maintain two different 'views' of an repository, one with access control showing the entire code, and one public with some directories removed.

Is this possible with git or svn? Perhaps by using some form of mirroring script?

I'd like to maintain the same revision in both repositories, and allow users of the public repository to submit patches.

Thanks in advance. This is an odd one, I think!

Edit for more information:

I develop a very large and reasonably complex open source application. Our users update directly from the svn at present, it works much better for our purposes than tarballs.

We have a publicly accessible svn repository, which allows us to quickly deploy fixes for small bugs and have everyone able to download them with a single command, we have a system for maintaining database schema too. Basically, we don't want to move away from this system.

We have a few features which are only available to commercial licensees (gotta pay for the carboard box and ramen somehow, right?). I'd basically like to move the 'master' repository to require authentication, and make the public repository a mirror of that repository with the non-free code removed.

For example, the authenticated user would see:

```
html/index.php
html/includes/functions.php
html/includes/non-free/functions.php
```

But the public user would see:

```
html/index.php
html/includes/functions.php
```

I really, really don't want to try to maintain two trees separately, it would probably result in the free version of the code lagging a lot, and would make it difficult for us to fix bugs for people on the free version.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure about Git, but you can use [path-based authorization](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.serverconfig.pathbasedauthz.html) in Subversion.

Something like this should work:

```
[yourRepo:/]
commercial = r
public = r

[yourRepo:/html/includes/non-free/]
public =
```

Comment: This is not quite what I want. :)

I'll edit the question to more clearly explain what I mean.

Comment: I've re-read your question, and I think that should work, have you tried it?

Comment: OP specified two repos but I believe that's a faulty requirement: based on  "[another directory might not even be readable by all but a few special people. As files are paths, too, it's even possible to restrict access on a per file basis.](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.pathbasedauthz.html)" SVN meets all the other criteria.  If you really need two repos, then you need them for unstated reasons -- and having multiple repos is the definition of a dvcs.  Almost certainly **much** better to add pattern-based authorization to git than dvcs to svn. (is @adama necessary)

Comment: Reading the docs on this, it seems there are some 'issues' with how it functions, notably that if the base repo is public, it will never ask for a user/pass to access non-public directories.

Answer (score 2):

Not-pretty and horribly inefficient, but would get the job done: have a private git repo that those with access can clone, fetch, and optionally push-to.  Use that to clone a repo, apply `git filter-branch` to remove stuff, and publish that as generally accessible.

For (untested) example, assuming a `--bare` repo on `some.host` that requires ssh access and is generally "private" and contains a `secret.txt` that's not supposed to be made public:

```
$ git clone --bare ssh://some.host/path/to/private.git new_public.git
$ cd new_public.git                      # don't let the public see this yet!
$ git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm --cached \
--ignore-unmatch secret.txt' -- --all    # add --tag-name-filter etc if needed
$ rm -rf refs/original                   # and do pruning, etc; see man page
# note (as per man page) that you can clone this again instead, might be easier
$ cd ..
$ mv new_public.git /path/to/public.git  # now it's safe; publish it
```

The commits in the public repo will differ from that in the private repo, but you can still take any patches made to the public repo.  Use `git apply` or `git am` to make them in (a clone of) the private repo ... then *re-generate* the public repo by doing the *same thing as before*: the same `git clone --bare`, `cd`-into-clone, `git filter-branch`, etc.  (You'll want to spend a lot of time setting up and testing the `filter-branch` arguments before publishing the first `public.git`, so the whole thing should go in a script anyway.)

The reason this works (well, I think it works, note that I haven't tested it) is that when `filter-branch` makes its changes to the all-new `new_public.git`, it makes the *same* changes as last time, starting from the *same originals*, resulting in bit-for-bit identical copies as before, so the commits will have the same SHA-1 values as the last time you did a `git filter-branch`.  Only any new commits added "on top" will differ and that's OK because they're new, on-top, fast-forward-style commits, to anyone using `public.git`.

It's not efficient because it redoes the same (quite heavy) work every time.  (To be efficient, instead of applying diffs just to the private repo, apply them to both private and public repos.  Automate this by writing a script that saves—somewhere—the private-repo state, computes all required patches, and applies all those patches to the public repo and then updates the saved private-repo state.  But if you get out of sync and have to redo the whole filter-branch thing, users of the public repo may get hosed, as this introduces a lot of opportunities for small differences, e.g., in commit timestamps.)

Comment: This won't work well because the two repositories are completely different, with different IDs for every commit. One of the requirements was to allow patches done on top of the public repository to be easily integrated in the private repositories, but since the commits don't match, they would have to be applied manually. However, given that the public files will look the same in the private repo, this shouldn't be a big problem. So, while this solution does accomplish what was requested, it does so by hurting performance a lot and by making patching extra hard.

Comment: @SergiuDumitriu: yes, I did say it would be horribly inefficient.